Proving that $\frac{a}{b}:\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a}{b}*\frac{d}{c}$
This is most likely a simple problem to solve. But I can`t wrap my head around coming up with a eloquent algebraic proof of why this is the case. I am a private math tutor for students in high school and would like to confidently show a proof for why this is the case. I often give examples of why this must be true, but I am longing for an algebraic proof of why this is always the case.
So why is $$\frac{a}{b}:\frac{c}{d}$$
the same as
$$\frac{a}{b}*\frac{d}{c}$$
?
I am sorry if this is too simple, but I would really like to be able to explain it to students with algebra if that`s possible. I have obviously looked around for a simple algebraic proof, but to no avail. Most people just explain it with examples and say that it must be so.
The last math course I took was when I did my economics degree, where we worked with derivatives and pre-calculus. That is my level of education.
With algebra I tried to set
$$\frac{a}{b}:\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a}{b}*\frac{d}{c}$$
and got an answer that said $$bc=1$$
I just have no idea what I am doing here, can someone help me out with an algebraic proof of why this must be true? I think it would really help me educate my students.

What are the definitions of these operations?  It seems to me that there is nothing to prove, and that these are simply definitions...

In specific words, "the ratio $a:b$ means $a\cdot\frac 1b$" or expanded as "$\frac ab:\frac cd$ means $\frac{\frac ab}{\frac cd}=\frac ab\cdot\frac dc$".

Although that may be the "proof" that OP is looking for, that the fraction in the denominator is flipped when moved into the numerator...

If you believe $a:b$ is different from $a/b$, then your equality cannot hold because LHS is a ratio, and RHS is a scalar. If you believe $a:b=a/b$, then you have LHS is $\dfrac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}}$, simplifying gives your RHS.

@DietrichBurde Not even then.

To prove that $x:y=z$, check that $zy=x$. Here, use $\frac dc\frac cd=\frac{dc}{cd}=1$.

The key point is that division is the the same as multiplying by an multiplicative inverse(A multiplicative inverse of $q$ is a number $s$ such that $q*s=1$): $a/b=a*\frac{1}{b} $ where $\frac{1}{b}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $b$ (as $b*\frac{1}{b}=1$).The multiplicative inverse of
$\frac{c}{d}$ is $\frac{d}{c}$(as $\frac{c}{d}*\frac{d}{c}=1$).            Thus $\frac{a}{b}/\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a}{b}*\frac{d}{c}$ .
